# Const correctness and operator *

Tags: c++, constants

I defined a class like this:

```
Quaternion& conjugate();        //negates the vector component of the quaternion
Quaternion  conjugate() const;  //same but in without modifying the class...

Quaternion& operator =  (Quaternion const& Qrhs);
Quaternion& operator *= (Quaternion const& Q);
Quaternion  operator  *  (Quaternion const& Qrhs) const;
```

now I use this functions like this:

```
PRINTVAR(*this);                //this is the first time printed (a little macro to print line and file)
Quaternion vQ(0.,vn), resQ;
resQ = vQ*(this->conjugate());  //this is the method I want to discuss...
PRINTVAR(*this);                //this is the second time
resQ = *this * resQ;
```

and this is the output

```
*this: (0:0:0:0) at line: 128 in file: Quaternions.cpp
*this: (-0:-0:-0:0) at line: 131 in file: Quaternions.cpp
```

I thought that by calling the operator * in the line `resQ = vQ*(this should be called as const)...`
why if I print `*this` again is changed?

here is the definition of the conjugate function:

```
Quaternion& Quaternion::conjugate(){
/* Given:  Nothing
 * Task:   Invert sign of the vector
 * Return: the class which will be modified
*/
    V3 vec;
    vec = -(this->getVector());
    x() = vec[0];
    y() = vec[1];
    z() = vec[2];
    return *this;
}

Quaternion Quaternion::conjugate() const{
    Quaternion result(*this);
    result.conjugate();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code you showed is in a non-const method, than the `this` pointer is non-const, and the non-const `conjugate` method is of course a better match than the const one. Return types aren't considered in overload decisions. If you want to insist that the const version is used, you can add constness: `resQ = vQ*(static_cast<const Quaternion*>(this)->conjugate());`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the method in which you are using `this` is non-const.

The type of `this` a member function of a type `A`, is `A * const`. For const member function it is `const A * const`.

Therefore, your code will work as you expect it to do if you enter your code into const method.

If you want to force calling const overload of function you will need to do a const-cast:

```
  const_cast<const Quaternion * const>(this)->conjugate();
```

Answer (score 0):

*this is not const (although it is used in a const method), and the [c++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.12) states regarding const overloading (in the FAQ's case on a subscript operator);

> When you apply the subscript operator to a MyFredList object that is
>   non-const, the compiler will call the non-const subscript operator.

Translated, since *this is non-const, the non-const method will be called.